# Cannot declare array of strings as class member

Tags: c++, string, declaration

I could not declare an array of strings in my class. Below my class definition:

```
class myclass{

    public:
        int ima,imb,imc;
        string luci_semaf[2]={"Rosso","Giallo","Verde"};
  };
```

and my main file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> 
#include "string.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;
#include "mylib.h"
int main() {

    return 0;
}
```

Why do I get the following warnings / error?

[image]

Comment: C ≠ C++. Also please [edit] your question to include the error message you are asking about *as text* instead of a tiny picture of three separate diagnostics.

Comment: First, value assignment should be in the constructor. Second, if you intend to assign 3 string values to your array then adjust the size to 3 as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not initialize data member.
You can write like this:

```
class myclass{
   public:
       myclass() {
            luci_semaf[0] = "Rosso";
            luci_semaf[1] = "Giallo";
            luci_semaf[2] = "Verde";
       }
   private:
       int ima,imb,imc;
       string luci_semaf[3];
 };
```

You can assign the values of the array in the Сonstructor

Comment: but one more question is: protected ofstream file;void creadata(string filename){file.open("txtfile/"filename".txt");} this is not working for me give me error16 [Error] expected ')' before 'filename'

Comment: write file path without "" please. And I will reply where errors

Comment: for eg ? without what ?

Comment: Without quotes because you added unnecessary

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97073/discussion-between-phoenix-and-evgeniy331).

Comment: This answer is _wrong_. There are no initialisations here.

Answer (score 6):

You have *two* problems: The first is that you can't initialize the array inline like that, you have to use a constructor initializer list. The second problem is that you attempt to initialize an array of two elements with *three* elements.

To initialize it do e.g.

```
class myclass{
public:
    int ima,imb,imc;
    std::array<std::string, 3> luci_semaf;
    // Without C++11 support needed for `std::array`, use
    // std::string luci_semaf[3];
    // If the size might change during runtime use `std::vector` instead

    myclass()
        : ima(0), imb(0), imc(0), luci_semaf{{"Rosso","Giallo","Verde"}}
    {}
};
```

Comment: You can initialize the array inline like that if you use C++11 or later as the message suggests.

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring an array of size 2 but providing 3 strings!

Comment: Because you use a feature of C++11, but you don't tell the compiler to use C++11. Add the option suggested in the message.

Answer (score 1):

Try storing the elements in vector of strings, in c++ vectors are used more often.

```
class myclass{

    public:
        int ima,imb,imc;
        std::vector<std::string> strings;
        myclass() {
           strings.push_back("blabla");
        }
  };
```

Comment: i use using namespace and what does mean vector<std::string> strings we have not done this yet

Comment: It means you are creating a vector that each element is of type string. Everything that is in <> it is a template argument. Read more about in C++ site about all the std features.

Comment: Add `#include <vector>` to your code to use `std::vector`.